# How to create two different figures based on the same previous one?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create **two different figures** based on the same **previous one**.

The previous one (`fig`) contains a line, **common for both figures**, from where two new figures are created (`fig1` and `fig2`), each of them with different data (`df1` and `df2`, respectively).

This is what I'd like to obtain:

[image]

I have tried using `fig.add_subplot` function, but an error is constantly raised:
`ValueError: The Subplot must have been created in the present figure`

I have created an **example** to show what I mean. The *Value Error* is shown when it's executed:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data for the two different figures
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(80), 'y':np.random.rand(80)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(10), 'y':np.random.rand(10)})


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Line creation for both figures
ax.plot(([1,2]))

# Try of creating the two different figures from the previous one:
fig1 = fig.add_subplot(df1.plot(x = 'x', y = 'y', kind = 'scatter'))
fig2 = fig.add_subplot(df2.plot(x = 'x', y = 'y', kind = 'scatter'))
```

In this example would be very easy to create the line inside of each figure, but that could not be done in the case that I'm working at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `ax` as an argument for `df.plot`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data for the two different figures
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(80), 'y':np.random.rand(80)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(10), 'y':np.random.rand(10)})


fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2)

# Line creation for both figures
ax[0].plot(([1,2]))
ax[1].plot(([1,2]))

# Try of creating the two different figures from the previous one:
df1.plot(x = 'x', y = 'y', kind = 'scatter', c='violet',ax=ax[0])
df2.plot(x = 'x', y = 'y', kind = 'scatter', c='navy',ax=ax[1])

ax[0].set_title('one')
ax[1].set_title('two')
```

the output figure is

[image: output]

---

**UPDATE**

The `ax` is an array of `Axes` objects. Different `Axes` objects are independent, they can have different labels, legends, ticks, etc. If you really need two figures for two plots

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data for the two different figures
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(80), 'y':np.random.rand(80)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(10), 'y':np.random.rand(10)})

# fig 1 
fig_0 = plt.figure(0)
ax_0 = fig_0.add_subplot(111)
ax_0.plot(([1,2]))
df1.plot(x = 'x', y = 'y', kind = 'scatter', c='violet',ax=ax_0)
ax_0.set_title('one')

fig_1 = plt.figure(1)
ax_1 = fig_1.add_subplot(111)
ax_1.plot(([1,2]))
df2.plot(x = 'x', y = 'y', kind = 'scatter', c='navy',ax=ax_1)
ax_1.set_title('two')

fig_0.savefig('one.png')
fig_1.savefig('two.png')
```

You will see from the two saved files, the two plots are in two different figures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @meTchaikovsky. And do you know what to do for making them independents?

Comment: @MiguelGonzalez You're welcome, what do you mean by making them independent?

Comment: I mean treat them as two figures, each one of them with just one plot. Then I have to deeply label them, and one's data is overlapped over other's data, so I think the best option is create two different figures. The line is just an example. Actually, instead of a line, the initial figure is conformed by plenty patches and subplots, so reached a point, I'd like to "copy" the axis-object and create two different graphics.

Comment: @MiguelGonzalez Yes, the two `Axes` objects are independent, they can have different properties, like different labels, ticks, etc. If you really need to construct two figures, check out my updated post.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate all your effort!
And do you think  these two lines could be created at the same time for the two figures?

`ax_0.plot(([1,2]))`
`ax_1.plot(([1,2]))`

Comment: @MiguelGonzalez You're welcome :) Of course they can, as long as `ax_0` and `ax_1` are created in the first place, it doesn't matter when to plot the lines. You can play with the code to see this :)